# why is object location swapped in JVM?

Tags: java

This is what I tried:

```
public final class firstObj{    
    public static void main(String args[]){    
        Object obj = new Object();    
        Object obj1 = new Object();    
        System.out.println(obj);
        System.out.println(obj1);    
    }    
}
```

I  compiled the program at first and ran it two consecutive times,
I got two different outputs:

output 1:

```
java.lang.Object@6f548414
java.lang.Object@65ab7626
```

output 2:

```
java.lang.Object@659c2931
java.lang.Object@6f548414
```

I want to know why did the JVM swap the second object's location to first object's location When it ran for the second time.., it is quite bewildering..,

Comment: Why do you care?  I'm not trying to be snarky.  The reason is buried deep in the details of platform-specific java memory management.  Unless you're doing something exotic/advanced just trust that java will figure that out.  If you have some specific need, then it seems you might be taking a problematic approach.

Comment: That number is based on the heap address of the object.  It's really random.

Comment: Two objects, even if they appear the same to you, won't necessarily be the same location in memory. Strings are unique in the sense that two Strings may share the same address, given they are identical (JVM magic happening here).

Comment: @SnakeDoc - If two strings "share" the same address, they are the same object.

Comment: @HotLicks that's what I was getting at... maybe I could be more clear.

Comment: I did not get the question properly. Are you saying that you have tried running the above program twice and you see the above result? if yes then whats the issue?

Comment: @ArpanAdhikari i could not get you.

Comment: @Trying, I first compiled the program, and then ran the program for two times sequentially only to see the above confusing output. .,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hashCode() has little to do with locations in memory.  While it might look like an address, it is just a randomly generated number.

> i was not expecting it to always allocate from the same segment, but i was wanted to know if the objects were allocated serially, as my output showed a little bit of such pattern

To be expected as it's a random number.

---

If you run this on OpenJDK or Oracle hotspot, you get.

```
import sun.misc.Unsafe;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class ObjectAddress {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o1 = new Object();
        Object o2 = new Object();
        Object o3 = new Object();
        Object[] os = {o1, o2, o3};
        System.out.println("Before using hashCode");
        for (int i = 0; i < os.length; i++) {
            int address = UNSAFE.getInt(os, UNSAFE.arrayBaseOffset(Object[].class) + i * 4);
            int hashCode = UNSAFE.getInt(os[i], 1L);
            System.out.println(i + ": " + Integer.toHexString(address) + " hashCode " + Integer.toHexString(hashCode));
            os[i].hashCode();
        }
        System.out.println("After using hashCode");
        for (int i = 0; i < os.length; i++) {
            int address = UNSAFE.getInt(os, UNSAFE.arrayBaseOffset(Object[].class) + i * 4);
            int hashCode = UNSAFE.getInt(os[i], 1L);
            System.out.println(i + ": " + Integer.toHexString(address) + " hashCode " + Integer.toHexString(hashCode) + " for " + os[i]);
            UNSAFE.putInt(os[i], 1L, 0x12345678);
        }
        System.out.println("After setting the hashCode");
        for (int i = 0; i < os.length; i++) {
            int address = UNSAFE.getInt(os, UNSAFE.arrayBaseOffset(Object[].class) + i * 4);
            int hashCode = UNSAFE.getInt(os[i], 1L);
            System.out.println(i + ": " + Integer.toHexString(address) + " hashCode " + Integer.toHexString(hashCode) + " for " + os[i]);
            os[i].hashCode();
        }

    }

    static final Unsafe UNSAFE;

    static {
        try {
            Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
            UNSAFE = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

you get something like

```
Before using hashCode
0: d8e78160 hashCode 0
1: d8e78170 hashCode 0
2: d8e78180 hashCode 0
After using hashCode
0: d8e78160 hashCode 68111f9b for java.lang.Object@68111f9b
1: d8e78170 hashCode 3c322e7d for java.lang.Object@3c322e7d
2: d8e78180 hashCode 3e2f1b1a for java.lang.Object@3e2f1b1a
After setting the hashCode
0: d8e78160 hashCode 12345678 for java.lang.Object@12345678
1: d8e78170 hashCode 12345678 for java.lang.Object@12345678
2: d8e78180 hashCode 12345678 for java.lang.Object@12345678
```

You can see that each Object is 16 bytes apart.

Comment: The location in memory could have an impact on the hashcode value "This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language." from [`hashcode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())

Comment: I love that sun has a package called `Unsafe`

Comment: @vandale It could, but it appears to be only part of a the random seed, but AFAIK usually isn't.

Comment: The [source code](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDoQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnesl.ee.ucla.edu%2Ffw%2Fchenni%2FChenni_desktop%2Fovero-oe%2Ftmp%2Fwork%2Farmv7a-angstrom-linux-gnueabi%2Fcacao-0.99.3-r11%2Fcacao-0.99.3%2Fsrc%2Fnative%2Fvm%2Fcldc1.1%2Fjava_lang_Object.c&ei=UKDBUraPC5e3sATylYHADQ&usg=AFQjCNHqFM_CuiW2g-BB8GIDxSXrsCkdxQ&sig2=ITymNK3-b8dg1Fv4QKkkVQ&bvm=bv.58187178,d.cWc) kinda suggests that the normal thing is to use the address.

Comment: @HotLicks If the hashCode was the address it would change when the object is moved around in memory. As you can see in my code, the hotspot JVM stores the hashCode in the object from the second byte.

Comment: @HotLicks BTW the OpenJDK is considered a reference implementation.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - It kinda looks like it might, for Object.  Other classes, of course, reimplement hashCode and save the result so it's invariant, but I'm not seeing how that would work for Object.

Comment: @HotLicks All `Object` have a header and 4 bytes reserved whether `hashCode()` overridden or not.  This can be accessed using `System.identityHashCode(x)`

Comment: (But whatever, the hashcode SHOULD be considered "random", with no relationship to when/where the object was created -- any apparent relationship is at the very least not "architected" (if not entirely coincidental).)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Been a while since I looked at the header, and that was an IBM version.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C, where a request for a new object returns a pointer which will throughout its lifetime be represented with the same unique bit pattern, most Java implementations store references using bit patterns that can change as the program runs (an object reference might store the physical location of an object in memory; if the GC wants to move an object, it will pause all threads, update every single reference to that object which exists anywhere in the universe to point to the new location, and then let threads continue).  Having an unchangeable mostly-unique 32-bit number available to describe each object is almost as useful as having an unchangeable 32-bit value which will be totally unique for each live object, or a 64-bit value that could be unique for every object ever created, but is cheaper and easier to implement (keeping a 64-bit value would increase by 8 bytes the storage required for each object, but would have the advantage of establishing a permanent ranking among all objects, which would be useful in some situations such as multiple-lock acquisition or caching; although establishing a permanent ranking for objects is sometimes useful, letting classes which need such ranking implement it themselves is probably better than having the system do it [though it might be helpful to have a system method which if called from multiple threads would return a guaranteed-unique 64-bit number which would be strictly increasing on each thread, and would overall correspond roughly with object age, but which would avoid the cost of an `AtomicLong` increment]

The hex numbers included in the default string representations of objects are not intended to have any meaning except that any given object will always report the same number, and distinct objects will *usually* report different numbers.  I don't know if there's any particular reason that the numbers appear random-ish rather than counting up from zero and then wrapping, but I would guess that the implementers of Java wanted to discourage people from doing anything that would rely upon objects' hash values having any relationship to each other.